# How To Add Search Functionality in ListView

Tags: android, listview, search, android-listview

how do i add Search Functionality in my android app?
i have a listview in which i want to add search functionality , i have the code but i dont know how do i integrate it properly with my app
here is the code -

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // When user changed the Text
    MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 @Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
}
});
```

and here is my java file

```
package com.Example.app;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView list1;

private String array[] = { "Iphone", "Tutorials", "Gallery", "Android",

"item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4", "item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4","item 1",        "item 2", "item3", "item 4"};


   @Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

// By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in

// list.

list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,

android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));

list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
     if (position == 1)
    {
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Baba.class);
      startActivity(myIntent);
    }
  }
});
}

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stackFromBottom="true">
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:hint="Search"
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword">
</EditText>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbarSize="5dp" 

    >

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/. check this blog

Comment: so what is the problem then?

Comment: What do you mean by own adapter? A custom adapter??

Comment: i see no custom adapter in your code. Also where is edittext. i gues you have not followed the blog full

Comment: dude then what is the problem in initializing edittext in onCreate and use the first part of the code in your post in onCreate.

Comment: post `activity_main.xml`. initialize edittext in onCreate. I do not see that part in your post. after initializatiom copy paste the 1st part of your post in `onCreate`. see if it works

Comment: Very nice tutorial here http://tech-papers.org/android-listview-search-using-filter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below

```
EditText inputSearch; 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch); // initialize edittext 
list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));
list1.setAdapter(adapter);
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // When user changed the Text
    MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 @Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
}
});
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
     if (position == 1)
    {
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Baba.class);
      startActivity(myIntent);
    }
  }
});
}
```

Initialize editText inputSearch in `onCreate`.

```
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch); // initialize edittext
```

Initialize adapter

```
adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));
```

Set the adapter op listview

```
list1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is where the search happens

```
 @Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // When user changed the Text
    MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   // filter based on input
}
```

Comment: @96 pls check the edit. pls make an effort to understand then copy paste the code

Comment: @96 what switch statement. you are totally confused. i don;t understand where is switch statement?? what is your requirement. You never mentioned anything in your post. But you expect a proper answer?

Comment: @96 i really don't understand what you are talking about. Seriously what string?

Comment: which code are you talking about. copy paste the whole code of `onCreate`. can't you even see the changes made? replace yours with mine

Comment: @96 becasue your code does not have that function. in onItemClick. you need to have the code that starts a new activity based on list item click. i see only this   `if (position == 1)
    {
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Baba.class);
      startActivity(myIntent);
    }`. So how can you say the code is useless without understanding  why it won't work

Comment: my code works fine and it launches the activity on second item click, but when im in the search thing and try to search for second item and launch it, nothing happens

Comment: @96 change to `Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityName.this,Baba.class);` it will work only when you click item at position 1. This is very basic stuff in android i suggest you read the docs.

Comment: @96 change this `Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Baba.class);` to `Intent myIntent = new Intent(ActivityName.this,Baba.class);`.can't you see the change. do i need to mention everything everytime. If you have further questions i suggest you ask a new question

Comment: what should i write at the place of activityname

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356187/android-search-not-opening-activities here you go

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using android's array adapter, you can use its [getFilter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getFilter%28%29) method too. So you just have to change minor things in your code.

Instead of setting array adapter like this

```
list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));
```

Create a private variable outside of the methods

```
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
```

Then initialize and set it

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
list1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now text changed method can call `MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);` without any problem