# Android Search Not opening activities

Tags: android, listview, search

i have implemented search functionality in my app, but whenever i pick an item from the search results, it won't launch the picked activity .according to the code , if i click on second item , it should fire the activity,

here is my code

```
package com.Example.app;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView list1;

private String array[] = { "Iphone", "Tutorials", "Gallery", "Android",

"item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4", "item 1", "item 2", "item3", "item 4","item 1",       "item 2", "item3", "item 4"};

EditText inputSearch; 
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch); // initialize edittext 
list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
list1.setAdapter(adapter);
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // When user changed the Text
 MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
    int arg3) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 @Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
}
});
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
 if (position == 1)
{
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Next.class);
  startActivity(myIntent);
 }
}
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change onItemClick to

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Next.class);
   startActivity(myIntent);
   // will launch activity every time an item in listview is clicked 
}
});
```

You have this

```
if (position == 1) // only if position is 1 
{
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Next.class);
 startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Use activity context instead of getApplicationContext as `MainActivity.this`

Edit:

```
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
   if(position==0)
   {
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Next.class);
   startActivity(myIntent);
   } 
   if(position==1)
   {
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivityName.class);
   startActivity(myIntent);
   } 
   ...// similar position 2 and 3 and so on
   }
   });
```

Comment: What to write at the place of "MainActivity"?

Comment: @96 MainActivity.this is the activity context. use that in place of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @96 on what basis (condition) should activity be launched?

Comment: you mean "use getApplicationContext() in place of that"?

Comment: @96 pls check the edit. copy onItemClick replace yours with mine

Comment: on clicking a row (each row should open different activity)

Comment: @96 check the edit now. instead of if else you can use switch case also. start different activity on each item click

Comment: do you have any idea about how do i make it open HTML files stored in assets folder at the place of activities and each html file should open in a webview

Answer (score 0):

You code will work on only the item at 1st position because you have done this in your listview item click listener :-

```
 if (position == 1)
{
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Next.class);
  startActivity(myIntent);
 }
```

only on the click on the item at 1st position, this if condition will come true and "Next" activity will be called