# Android - How to I implement a search functionality and return the results back in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, search

I have an EditText where user can type any text they want (eg. “A”, or  “B” or “C”) from an array of Strings (arr [] = “A”, “B”, “C”). I have a ListView where I want the results to be displayed when user clicks "done" button on the keyboard? How do I do this in my code?

here is a screenshot:
[image]

Here is my code?

```
package com.mobilecomp.add.ssproj1;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}



package com.mobilecomp.add.ssproj1;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.mobilecomp.add.ssproj1.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/inputText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchResult"
        android:layout_below="@+id/inputText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: When search should be done? When clicked some button?

Comment: I don't checked it but i found this two links: 

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355177/how-to-add-search-functionality-in-listview

Comment: when done button is clicked

Comment: thanks Krystian I  have looked at the links but their code is different from mine as I'm using fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add some `Button` to your `fragment_main` with `android:id=@+id/button`. Then in your fragment:

```
private ListView mListView;
private EditText mEditText;
private Button mButton;
private ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    mListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.searchResult);
    mEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.inputText);
    mButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //Some random data...
    mData.add("A");
    mData.add("B");
    mData.add("C");

    //Trigger, set listener on sth... button example
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String fromEditText = mEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            for (String aaa : mData) {
                if (aaa.contains(fromEditText)) {
                    mAdapter.add(aaa);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

---

Edit:

Instead of setting listener on `mButton`, you can do:

```
    mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                    || event.getAction() == KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION) {
                final String fromEditText = mEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                for (String aaa : mData) {
                    if (aaa.contains(fromEditText)) {
                        mAdapter.add(aaa);
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks N1to. I wonder if it's possible to do it without creating an additional button? I just want the user to click "done" using the keyboard

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is use `TextWatcher`

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```