# Add click to results of TextWatcher

Tags: android, listview, textwatcher

I am trying to build search option with TextWatcher On listview. After the results shown, how to make results clickable? I can add Onitemclick on listview but it doesn't help, it doesn't make results clickable.

Comment: use `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`

Comment: @pskink is correct you need AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.

Comment: @AdarshYadav Will you please give example?? i have not implemented before..

Comment: @MayankKhursija Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20355499/1384010

Comment: Not working... Still I cant get to new active while clicking on listview item by filtering.. @AdarshYadav

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code for your reference.

```
public class AndroidListViewFilterActivity extends Activity {

 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = null;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  //Generate list View from ArrayList
  displayListView();

 } 

 private void displayListView() {

  //Array list of countries
  List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<String>();
  countryList.add("India");
```

//     .. add multiple country here

```
  //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
  dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.country_list, countryList);
  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  // Assign adapter to ListView
  listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

  //enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView
  listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {
    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
     ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  });

  EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
  myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  }

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
   dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
  }
  });
 }   
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp"
  android:text="@string/some_text" android:textSize="20sp" />

 <EditText android:id="@+id/myFilter" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ems="10"
  android:hint="@string/some_hint">

  <requestFocus />
 </EditText>

 <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

This code is working fine for me.

Comment: But By clicking on listview item , it is not going to another Activity while searching..

Comment: In adapter try to use the textView onClick & TextView onClick() set the selected text to EditText

Comment: cant get it. please describe @MaheshwarLigade

Comment: in adapter It's not optimised way but it is solution
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

// set the selected value to the Editext 
}
}